# Laravel - How to setup a morphOne relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I'm trying to implement a morphable table for categories, right now I've the following.

```
// Snippet Table
- id
- title
- body

// Post Table
- id
- title
- body

// Category Table
- id
- name
```

I want to be able to morph the posts and snippets to have only one category, something like this:

```
// Categorizable Table
- category_id
- categorizable_id
- categorizable_type
```

Do I have to have another model for this categorizable table? Or there is a way to set it without another model?

So far I have this

```
class Snippet extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function categorizable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And I have 4 tables, `snippets`, `posts`, `categories`, `categorizables`, the last one the migration looks like this.

```
Schema::create('categorizables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->morphs('categorizable');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The thing is, what is the correct way to save this relationship, I'm testing it on tinker and both`attach($category_id)` and `sync($category_id)` aren't saving the relationship they return the error `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::categorizable()'`, What I'm missing?

Comment: Read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @yazfield the documentation shows a morphToMany, and that is not the case, I need a morphOne, in a one-to-one polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry I thought you wanted many-to-many relationship. `morphOne` relationship API is the same as `morphMany` from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

```
Post extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

Category extends Model
{
    public function categorizable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
When using morphOne you don't need a pivot table `categorizables` table must be deleted and change your `categories` table to include the morph fields

```
// Category Table
- id
- name
- categorizable_id
- categorizable_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question based on your answer, but I think I'm missing something, the category relationship always return null, I've set some itens on the database by hand, and even this way it returns null, the way I can't save the relationship or return it.

Comment: I got it now, thanks for the help, in the end, I don't think this is what I'll need. =/

Comment: I did this but was not working and found out I needed to do one more step.
Adding an entry in the Relation::morphMap

i.e.
`Relation::morphMap([
    'category' => Category::class
]);`

Reference: [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: It's not only 'morphOne' for which you don't need a pivot table. For 'morphMany' you also don't need it. Except for when its an N-to-N relationship of course.

Comment: Why is it that the answer and the docs does not state on how to use it